# How do I prevent my page to reload or refresh on submitting the HTML form (textarea) on a button click?

Tags: html

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post">
       <label class="left margin-left-10">Involve in discussion</label>
       <br>
      <textarea name="chat" placeholder="Write.." cols="20" wrap="soft" maxlength="1000" class="left"></textarea>
      <button name="sendmsg" class="background-none text-white background-primary-hightlight text-s-size-12">Send</button>
<form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent form from being submitted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Comment: Send the form somewhere or submit it via AJAX. Also `<form>` should be `</form>` that is currently opening a second `form`.

Comment: Doesn't look like it would submit to me, with just a <button>

Comment: Is there jquery, javascript, PHP as well?

Comment: I am using PHP in back end sorry I missed pasting </form> here..

Comment: @HaydenThring The default type of a button in a form is to submit, if undeclared. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-type-BUTTON

Comment: What about my question?

Comment: I addressed that 7 minutes ago. `Send the form somewhere or submit it via AJAX.`

Comment: @chris85 thanks i did have that suspicion, what if he used a <input> type button, or but the button outside the form, otherwise there is javascript

Comment: @HaydenThring `type=button` is different than `<button>` a `button` type does nothing by default. I use that if JS is handling the processing.

Comment: Any clue how to send it with AJAX?

Comment: Look up ajax jquery docs for that, but you will make it simpler if you avoid that if possible. Just trigger the form submit with javascript, or interact with the form with javascript. You havent really said what you want to do with the form apart from just not submit it normally...

Comment: @HaydenThring i am making a message box, in that i am receiving and sending messages. Now coming back to this form I am sending a message which is the value user inputs in <textarea>. The problem is every time I submit the form the page refreshes. I want to prevent that refresh. I hope you understand now.

Comment: Sure, than if you want to submit and receive data without page load/refresh you need ajax, look up the simplified $.get and $.post commands in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
<button name="sendmsg" class="background-none text-white background-primary-hightlight text-s-size-12">Send</button>
```

This

```
<input type="button" value="Send" name="sendmsg" class="background-none text-white background-primary-hightlight text-s-size-12" />
```

Comment: My main problem is to prevent page refresh on submitting the form on a button click. Is this replacement a solution? Hayden Thring

Comment: Correct, it should do nothing when clicked with the replacement code suggested.

Comment: You can also just use `type="button"` in the original code, so that the button isn't a submit button.

Comment: so <button type="button" ? thats interesting, so its overrides the normally default button type="submit" ?

Comment: @HaydenThring I just removed the button now sumitting it with the Enter key.

Comment: If you dont want to do that you can use the onsubmit option in the form tag , and simply return false https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp